# WebDriverException : It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found

Tags: java, appium, appium-android

I am trying my first appium sample (API demo),

Below is sample code I am running,

```
File f = new File("src");
File fs = new File(f,"ApiDemos-debug.apk");

//Set the Desired Capabilities
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();

caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, fs.getAbsolutePath());

caps.setCapability("udid", "712KPYR0867800");
caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Pixel 2 XL"); 
caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.1.0");

//Instantiate Appium Driver
try {
    AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());

}
```

When I try to run above piece of code on real device,I am getting following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible'

Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:195)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:209)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:231)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:84)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:94)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:93)
at com.appium.example.FirstTestAppiumClass.main(FirstTestAppiumClass.java:37)

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find a connected Android device.
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: try restarting your appium server. If this work i have a solution. Does restarting appium server work?

Comment: @Suban, Thanks for reply, I am able to fix,Its related path and some jar issue after correcting this I restarted system its working fine.

Comment: Is it working fine now?

Comment: Yes its working fine

Comment: Can you be more specific and post your fix?  I'm having the same problem.  What path/jar was "corrected" and in what way?

Comment: @Joe Can you please describe your fix in detail, I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Running Appium Server as Administrator works for me :)